# Replace or supplement very old attic insulation

Tags: insulation, attic

My attic has very old insulation, which [I have been told provides very little R-value](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/213310/9354). I suspect the insulation was from when the house was built in 1909.

**Question:** Should I remove this old insulation before putting fiberglass batts or just put batts on top of it? (*The beams are 6"*).

[image]

Comment: What is the old insulation.

Comment: I do not know what it is called, it is like little woolly pellets

Comment: Blow in cellulose may be a better option.

Comment: @AlaskaMan was thinking about it but requires a rental. Batts are more laid back work, can be done peacemeal

Comment: Given the choice i would rent the machine and blow it. (*and i have*) Quicker and no fiberglass. Getting batts in the hard to reach places is HARD.

Comment: Most stores that sell cellulose "rent" the machine at no cost. I would definitely go that route even if there was a charge. It'll be vastly easier and you'll have a better outcome. You will need to block any soffit air paths first.

Comment: @Ishwood-Don't block the soffit's opening. Air needs to circulate.

Comment: Blocking the cellulose from getting into the air paths, not blocking the air paths themselves, is what isherwood means. They make pre-cut pieces vent chutes, in plastic or cardboard, that can just be stapled to the rafters.

Answer (score 3):

That insulation is most likely what  my father-in-law bought for his home in the 1960's. It was called "pouring wool", sold in bags and was very itchy. I was dating his daughter, now my wife of 58 years, and I offered to install it for him. (you can guess why). We did the job in JULY. I wasn't too smart back then. It looks just like that . I would just install batts over top of that insulation. Make sure that you do not cover the soffit vents and do not fill up into the roof joists. They have styrofoam vents that go between the roof sheeting and the insulation. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since it was installed to insulate the room below and though it has become compacted and lost some R-value it still is insulating. How ever little that may be.

Also I would be suspicious of harmful additives used at the time that can cause health issues. Disturbing this stuff will only allow dust to become airborne.

Lastly, why incur the added expense and effort that would come with it's removal? It makes me shudder to even consider it!

Best plan is to seal all openings to the living space below with foam and caulk. If you plan on using rolled insulation lay it parallel to the joists. If you decide on more lay the second layer perpendicular to the first (like plywood is made).

Or you can blow in insulation which is faster,but takes a bit more planning.

Try to achieve a total R-value of 38 or higher if your in a cold winter climate.

Comment: So are you saying remove the old or leave it? Removal is very easy, can be scooped and put in a bag

Comment: @amphibient  "*Removal is very easy*"  As some who has tried that i can say, it is not easy.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I have removed sections already. It's like wool pellets sitting on top of the ceiling

Comment: @amphibient- I would never try to dissuade a man to not work. To me it seems like an unnecessary effort and expense.

Comment: @amphibient-the only upside I can see is it will help to locate openings needing foam.

Comment: putting down planks to work off helps.

Comment: "seal all openings to the living space below" is a great idea, but difficult to find them with all that stuff in the way. "R-value of 38" is a good recommendation (depending on locale), however, with the old stuff (likely not providing much R/inch) in the way, it will take piling the new insulation even higher. If the OP's willing to do the work (he sounds eager to do so), there's no reason _not_ to remove the old stuff.

Comment: Can I face fiberglass insulation up (opposite of what it would be of i were installing it before ceiling sheet rock as I would be stapling the paper to joists) or should I get unfaced or can I just peel the paper off?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214311/does-facing-fiberglass-batts-matter-when-installing-from-attic

Comment: @amphibient- the paper face must face the living space. It's important to install insulation between joists so that no gaps are created. If joist spacing is 16 o/c it should be easy. If not consider blown in loose fill. Also consider sealing attic and using no paper face and/or a 2nd layer of batts or blown in on top. keep soffit vents clear and build walls around furnaces to keep blown out. remember recessed lights may not be designed for insulation covering. seal around chimney chases with silicone and keep insulation away from it.

Comment: @amphibient- unfaced batts will work especially if joists are not spaced 16 o/c. They are usually wider than  14 1/2" and 48-60" long. They are acceptable for your attic and climate zone. (more is better in the attic!).