# Does facing fiberglass batts matter when installing from attic?

Tags: insulation, attic

I would like to supplement some existing old woolly pellet insulation in my attic using 6" thick fiberglass batts. Since the size I need seems to only come faced, should I:

1. Face it up (facing the roof, opposite what it would be if I were installing it from the room below on its ceiling) and be able to staple it to joists, or
2. Face it down and not staple it, or
3. Peel the paper off?

Comment: why fiberglass in attic?   its a lot more work and not as efficient...  Are you planning on having a workspace there?

Comment: I don't want to rent the blowing machine

Comment: Also, place them over the top of the joists - not between. The joists conduct heat. Check if your local code allows this - you may have to place some marker pegs (made of drywall) through the insulation so people can see where the joists are. This is so you get the insulation value of the air pocket.

Comment: @amphibient - they are generally free if you buy a certain amount of insulation.   I can't imagine stapling batts down compared to using a blower for 2 hours.    Crazy talk.

Answer (score 1):

Face down, if you are in a mostly-heating climate. Vapor barrier goes to the warm side.

Comment: Would it be preferable to use no face batts?

Comment: I'm in mid Atlantic, equal heat and cool

Comment: ...one more reason in favor of renting the machine and blowing cellulose (it does moisture management and reduction of air movement really well compared to fiberglass, and in a 50/50 climate that's a good thing.)

Comment: I have roof vents for moisture

Comment: And in cooling season they let it right in...

Comment: vents can be hooded

Comment: One more question: would unfaced batts be preferable if I could find them in the size I need?